# Initializing Arrays in C/C++ With Unknown Size

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

How can I initialize an array in C such as

```
void initArr(int size)
{
  ...
}
```

The C language does not give the option to initialize an array
if his size is not an constant value, and if I initialize
it generally (int *arr;) so it gives me error of 'arr' is not
being initialized.

Similarily, how can I do that when I have an array with dimension
bigger than one (matrix, for example)?

Comment: The C language (at least the C99 version) does give you that option. C++ does not. Choice of language is very important here, so pick one.

Comment: If "int size" is specified, then the size is not unknown, right ?

Comment: Is it C? or C++? It cannot be both.

Comment: I'm working on the C language

Comment: @Johnny The you either need to look at Variable Length Arrays which are supported in the C99 dialect of C. Or if you don't have that available you need to look at using dynamic memory allocation using malloc or similar. These are big topics so it's not really possible to describe all the details in a forum post.

Comment: And the main reason for my question is
this function:

double** allocMatrix(int rows, int cols)
{
 int i, j;
 double **mat;

 for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
 {
  for(j = 0; j < cols; j++)
  {
   mat[rows][cols] = 0;
  }
 }

 return mat;
}

Comment: @Johnny: Based on that last comment, I think you should make your question clearer. People answering questions don't usually read all the comments first in order to understand the question. I have a feeling that what you wanted to know was something like "Is there a more efficient/less cumbersome/prettier way to initialize an object whose size is not known at compile time."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer that works in C and C++ is dynamic memory allocation

```
int *arr = (int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
```

In C++ you would prefer to use new instead of malloc, but the principle is the same.

```
int* arr = new int[size];
```

Comment: Though in C++ you should rather use containers such as `std::vector<int>` instead of raw arrays. You should also free any unused memory, that you allocated, with `free(arr)` (C) or `delete[] arr` (C++).

Comment: Correct answer, but please mention `sizeof` for "array with dimension bigger than one". ("Initialize" -- wouldn't this be equivalent to "declare", where zeroing the memory would "initialize" it?)

Answer (score 1):

> The C language does not give the option to initialize an array if his size is not an constant value

In C99 you can use a variable length array and then initialize it by using a loop.

> if I initialize it generally (int *arr;) so it gives me error of 'arr' is not being initialized.

This is because a pointer must be initialized (points to a pointee - excluding NULL) before it is being used in program.

Comment: C99 does *not* give you the option to initialize a variable length array. Section 6.7.9 (Initialization) "3. The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or a complete
object type that is not a variable length array type."

Answer (score 0):

In C, you can initialize objects to 0 with `memset`. It's not possible to use `memset` to portably initialize objects other than character arrays to a repeated non-zero value.

In C++, the same is true, but it is restricted to so-called "POD" objects (Plain Old Data), which are basically the same objects you could have in C (no virtual functions, no private data members, etc. -- the precise definition is in the standard). It's not good C++ style, but it's possible.

In both C and C++ you can find the total size of an array in bytes (which you need to pass to `memset`) by multiplying the dimensions and the size of a single data element. For example:

```
void InitializeMatrix(double *m, size_t rows, size_t cols) {
  memset(m, 0, rows * cols * sizeof *m);
}
```

In C99, you can declare a variable length array (VLA), even with multiple dimensions, and if you do so, you can use the `sizeof` operator directly on the array, which can be a lot more convenient. But there are lots of restrictions on VLAs; they often don't work the way you expect them to. However, the following does work:

```
double m[rows][cols];
memset(m, 0, sizeof m);
```

Note that in C99, unlike traditional C or C++, the compiled `sizeof` operator in this case may actually create run-time code, and therefore violates the expectation of many programmers that `sizeof` does not evaluate its argument.

Comment: In short, after explanasions, I think I can
write it down that way:

TYPE DIM_NUM arr = (TYPE DIM_NUM)malloc(SIZE * size(TYPE DIM_NUM-1));

Thank you all!!! Your answers really helped :)